# Which statistical test should be used for GC-content comparison?

Tags: statistics, biostatistics, nucleic-acids, research-tools, research-design

I'm predicting that certain genes (n=20) are more GC rich than expected in all protein-coding genes. How can I test this hypothesis efficiently?

I generated the same number of random genes (also n=20) and calculated GC content for them. After using the t-test (2-tailed, two-sample unequal variance) it shows a significant P < 0.005 result. But I'm not sure that I can interpret it with high confidence.

Comment: Crossposted https://www.biostars.org/p/9525660/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try a [permutation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_test). These are a kind of **[non-parametric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics)** statistical test which involve creating your own [null distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_distribution) from your data.

Your hypothesis $H_{1}$ in this case, is that your gene set has a higher GC content than expected by chance. Similarly, your null hypothesis, $H_{0}$ is that there is there is no difference between your set a random set of gene from the population. You are interested in a p-value, which simply asks what the probability of obtaining  a test result at least as extreme as the result actually observed, under the assumption that the null hypothesis is correct.

So thus to obtain a p-value and take say, 1000 random samples of protein-coding genes and calculate their GC content to obtain a null distribution. Then to obtain a p-value that your gene set has a higher GC content than expected under the null, take the proportion of the null distribution greater than your gene set.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you should be comparing your 20 genes against all other protein coding genes in the same organism.

A statistical test comparing the proportion of GC nucleotides in your sample to the rest may be the one to use.